# LNK2005 error, already defined in main.obj

Tags: c++

So ive been writing my code for a bit now and im not the best coder in the world.  im still learning and consider myself a beginner.  im writing a lexical analysis for a concepts class in c++.  Ive tried the solutions ive seen on websites like this such as using extern in the header file and using const in the cpp files, but noting works.when i include my header file in 2 separate .cpp files i get this error for all the ints in the header file:

tokens.obj : error LNK2005: "int eND" (?eND@@3HA) already defined in main.obj

header file=

```
#include <string.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

extern int lANGLE=1, rANGLE=2,iD=3, eQ=4, sLASH=5, qSTRING=6, oTHER=7, eND=8, tEXT=9;

map <int, int> counter;

extern int getToken(istream *br, string& lexeme);
```

token.cpp(declaring what getToken does)

```
#include "suffix.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <cctype>

bool slash = false;
bool text = false;
bool quote = false;
bool id = false;
bool equ =  false;
bool other = false;
bool qstring = false;
char prev=NULL;

int getToken(istream *in, string& lexeme)
{
    char c;
    char prev;
    lexeme="";

    int intSlash = 0;

    int intText = 0;

    int intQuote = 0;

    int intId = 0;

    int intEqual = 0;

    int intOther = 0;

    int intQstring = 0;

    int langlec = 0;
    int  intLangle = 0;

    int ranglec = 0;
    int  intRangle = 0;

    if (in->eof())
        return eND;

    while (in->get(c))
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '/' :
                if (quote == false && langlec > 0)
                {
                slash = true;
                intSlash++;
                return 5;
                }
                break;

            case '=' :
                if (quote == false && langlec > 0)
                {
                 equ = true;
                intEqual++;
                return 4;
                }
                break;

            case '<' :

                if (  prev != ' '  && langlec == 0) 
                    {intText++ ;
                return 9;}

                if (quote == false)
                {
                    langlec ++;
                    intLangle ++;
                    id = true;
                    return 1;
                }


                break;


            case '>' :

                if (quote != true)
                {
                    ranglec++;
                    intRangle++;
                    return 2;

                    if (langlec > 0)
                    {
                        langlec--;
                        id = false;
                    }
                }   
                break;

            case '"' :
                if (langlec > 0 && quote == true)
                {
                    quote = false;
                    id = true;
                    intQstring ++;
                    intOther--;
                    return 6;
                }
                else if (langlec > 0)
                {
                    intOther++;
                    quote = true;   
                    return 7;
                }



                break;

            case ' ':
                if ( prev != ' ' && prev != '<' && prev != '>' && quote == false){
                    if (langlec == 0){
                        intText++;
                        return 9;
                    }
                }
                    else if ( prev != '/' && prev != '=')
                        {intId++;
                        return 3;
                    }

                break;

            default:

                if (quote == true)
                    {
                        id = false;
                    }

                else if (id==true) 
                    {
                        intId++;
                        id=false;
                        return 3;
                    }
                prev=c;

        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "suffix.h"

using namespace std;

int
main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
 istream *br;
 ifstream infile;
 // check args and open the file
if( argc == 1 )


br = &cin;
 else if( argc != 2 ) {
cout<<"THERE IS A FATAL ERROR"<<endl; 
return 1; // print an error msg
 } else {
 infile.open(argv[1]);
 if( infile.is_open() )
 br = &infile;
 else {
 cout << argv[1] << " can't be opened" << endl;
 return 1;

 }
}
string tokens="";
int typeOfToken;

while(true){
    typeOfToken=getToken(br,tokens);
    if (counter.count(typeOfToken))
        counter[typeOfToken]+=1;
    else
        counter[typeOfToken]=1;

    if(typeOfToken==8)
        break;
}
cout<<"total token count: "<<endl;
if (counter[1]!=0)
    cout<<"LANGLE: "<<counter[1]<<endl;
if (counter[2]!=0)
    cout<<"RANGLE: "<<counter[2]<<endl;
if (counter[9]!=0)
    cout<<"TEXT: "<<counter[9]<<endl;
if (counter[3]!=0)
    cout<<"ID: "<<counter[3]<<endl;
if (counter[4]!=0)
    cout<<"EQ: "<<counter[4]<<endl;
if (counter[5]!=0)
    cout<<"SLASH: "<<counter[5]<<endl;
if (counter[6]!=0)
    cout<<"QSTRING: "<<counter[6]<<endl;
if (counter[7]!=0)
    cout<<"OTHER: "<<counter[7]<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're defining it in the header, so it gets defined in both files. You need to *declare* it in the header, and *define* it in only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern int lANGLE=1, ...  eND=8
```

This is supposed to be `extern` declaration, but due to explicit initialization it's actually a definition. So you end up defining all these variables in several translation units, leading to violation of [One Definition Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

When you fix this, you'll have the same problem with `map <int, int> counter;`

What you should do is to answer yourself the question, why do you have to declare all of these in a header file. `map <int, int> counter;` is used only in `main.cpp`, so move it there. And the `int` variables can be replaced with one `enum`, because it seems you are going to use them as return values for `getToken()`.

So it will be something like

```
enum Token {
    lANGLE=1, rANGLE=2,iD=3,...
};

Token getToken(istream *br, string& lexeme);
```

Comment: if i change the int to an enum, would i have to change the map from map<int,int> to map<token, int>? Also in the main class im getting an error of argument of type int is incompatible with parameter of type const tokentype& on line: "if (counter.count(typeOfToken))"

Comment: Also in the main class im getting an error of argument of type int is incompatible with parameter of type const tokentype& on line:                    "if (counter.count(typeOfToken))"                               and in the line                                                   counter[typeofToken]+=1; there is an error of no operator[] matches these operands

Comment: @curryboy127 you don't have to change the type of `counter` because `enum` is implicitly convertible to `int`, but it won't hurt. I made the changes to your code and it compiles just fine, see [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a3e33100c44d131)